# Using local test server for React-Native app using a web browser? (npm package React-native-browser)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I'm trying to run a local test server to test adjustments to a view written in html for my app. I'm using the package react-native-browser.

The project name is Bowser, just to minimize confusion.

Both 'localhost:3000' and 'https://localhost:3000' as strings for Browser.open()'s first arg don't work.

What's the proper way of implementing this? Am I meant to use react-native-http for this to work?

```
    var Browser = require('react-native-browser');
    export default class Bowser extends Component {
        render() {
            //also tried https://localhost:3000
            Browser.open('localhost:3000', {
                showUrlWhileLoading: false
                , navigationButtonsHidden: true
                , showActionButton: false
                , showDoneButton: false
                , showPageTitles: false
                , disableContextualPopupMenu: false
                , hideWebViewBoundaries: true
            });
            return ( < View style = {
                    styles.container
                } > < Text style = {
                    styles.welcome
                } > Welcome to React Native! < /Text> < Text style = {
                    styles.instructions
                } > To get started, edit index.ios.js < /Text> < Text style = {
                    styles.instructions
                } > Press Cmd + R to reload, {
                    '\n'
                }
                Cmd + D or shake
                for dev menu < /Text> < /View>);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using React Native's built-in WebView component? And also, your simulator may not connect by localhost, get your computer's local IP, and try using it instead.

Comment: @EnieJakiro
I'm really new to R-N. Thank you for the suggestions! I'll give them a shot

Comment: try finding your computer's IP address using either ( ifconfig | grep inet ) in mac terminal or ( ipconfig/ALL ) in windows cmd. One of these should work as the WebView uri: exhttp://194.178.1.2:4242/my-local-endpoint